# Pandas subtract two data frames by non-numeric values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames like :

**df :**

```
    a       b         c      d
0  12   "vik"   [9,  18]   "SS"
1  13   "Rah"   [10, 18]   "YY"
```

**df2 :**

```
    a       b         c      d
0  12   "vik"   [9,  18]   "SS"
1  13   "Rah"   [10, 18]   "YY"
2  14   "Dil"   [11, 18]   "ZZ"
```

I want to eliminate the rows from df2 which are in df. I have tried

```
df2.sub(df, fill_values=0)
```

which gives me an error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`.

My desired output is like :

```
    a       b         c      d
0  14   "Dil"   [11, 18]   "ZZ"
```

Any helps are appreciable.

Comment: @bro-grammer - unfortunately not, if change index values of `df2` it failed.

Comment: Ah Yes! You are right. Good catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and parameter `indicator=True`, then filter by [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) and remove column `_merge`:

```
df1['c'] = df1['c'].apply(tuple)
df2['c'] = df2['c'].apply(tuple)

df3 = (df2.merge(df, how='left', indicator=True)
          .query('_merge == "left_only"')
          .drop('_merge', axis=1))

df3['c'] = df3['c'].apply(list)
print (df3)
    a    b         c   d
2  14  Dil  [11, 18]  ZZ
```

Comment: It shows error `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: @VikasDamodar - Processing list in pandas is really problematic, need convert columns to tuples. Check edited answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is one approach using `concat` and `drop_duplicates`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": [12, 13], "b":["vik", "Rah"], "c":[[9,  18], [10, 18]], "d":["SS", "YY"]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"a": [12, 13, 14], "b":["vik", "Rah", "Dil"], "c":[[9,  18], [10, 18], [11, 18]], "d":["SS", "YY", "ZZ"]})

df3 = pd.concat([df, df2], ignore_index=True)
df3["c"] = df3["c"].apply(tuple)
print(df3.drop_duplicates(keep=False))
```